# p5.js Nested For Loop not iterating

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested, p5.js

I am trying to create some scales measuring sound frequency for a music visualiser project. They are meant to display 4 different frequencies ( bass, lowMid, highMid and treble in a 2x2 grid pattern.  I'm nearly there I have my rectangles but the needle which measures and shows the frequency itself is only iterating for the top row x and not the bottom row. I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I'm sure it could be something very simple that I'm missing.

```
    // draw the plots to the screen
    this.draw = function() {
        //create an array amplitude values from the fft.
        var spectrum = fourier.analyze();
        //iterator for selecting frequency bin.
        var currentBin = 0;
        push();
        fill('#f0f2d2');
        //nested for loop to place plots in 2*2 grid.
        for(var i = 0; i < this.plotsDown; i++) {
            for(var j = 0; j < this.plotsAcross; j++) {

                //calculate the size of the plots
                var x = this.pad * j * 10;
                var y = height/20 * i * 10;
                var w = (width - this.pad) / this.plotsAcross;
                var h = (height - this.pad) / this.plotsDown;

                //draw a rectangle at that location and size
                rect(x, y, w, h);

                //add on the ticks
                this.ticks((x + w/2), h, this.frequencyBins[i])

                var energy = fourier.getEnergy(this.frequencyBins[currentBin]);

                //add the needle
                this.needle(energy, (x + w/2), h)

                currentBin++;
            }
        }

        pop();
    };
```

Comment: x = this.pad*i and then rect(x*i,  do you really need to multiply by i twice? That looks suspect to me. Same for j.. maybe that is what you want..

Comment: Sorry that was me editing part of the code and not the rest. I fixed it and it still doesn't work?